# actionscript 3 (about ysqu, ydf, and ymo)(making menu)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

i am handling with a flash assignment right now. 
however, there is trouble from changing as2 to as3

will u know what is the code for as3?

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
Ysqu = _root.menu._y;
Ydf = Ypa-Ysqu;
Ymo = Ydf/10;
_root.menu._y = Ysqu+Ymo;
updateAfterEvent(enterFrame);
}
```

thanks so much!!

Comment: I am not a fan of these AS2-AS3 conversion questions.

Answer (score 0):

To know conversions, you must understand them...

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, sup);
function sup(e:Evt):void
{
Ysqu = MovieClip(root).menu.y;
Ydf = Ypa-Ysqu;
Ymo = Ydf/10;
MovieClip(root).menu.y = Ysqu+Ymo;
e.updateAfterEvent
}
```

You will get a warning about updateevent, but it still works.

`_y` is changed to `y`.  `OnClipEvent` is changed to `addEventListener`.  `_root` is changed to `MovieClip(root)`.